# AS#3 Array is not clearing its contents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

Firstly i will briefly explain:

I have 2 Arrays, the first Array:holder, the second Array:Clips.
The first array was dynamic empty boxes as a Grid pattern through a loop pushing each item into an array and adding to the stage// just for the locations x,y

The Second array:Clips are dynamically loaded SWF Movies, 10 all together
These  loaded SWF clips are "addChild" into the Holder Array, so these clips will be in the grid pattern and at the same time pushed into the array Clips, for reference example

```
     Clips[1].x = 50 ; // this works fine
```

so i know my clips are in there, reference correctly. But what icant seem to do is remove all contents from array:Clips

```
      var len:int = Clips.length;
      for( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      this.removeChild( Clips[i] ) ;        
      }
```

i have tried splice aswell with same result just either throws errors or does nothing, either way my items are not deleting / removed off staged.

easy way to explain i load 15 items in an array, everytime the button is pressed i want clear that array and re-populate with another 15 items this happens every 10 seconds for ever..

I can repopulate no problem it will keep loading more stuff over the old content but i want the old content to be cleared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent errors, amend your condition:

```
if(this.contains(Clips[i]){
    this.removeChild(Clips[i]);
}
```

If it's still not working, you may be removing from the wrong clip, ie not 'this' - try this:

```
if(Clips[i] != null && Clips[i].parent != null){
        Clips[i].parent.removeChild(Clips[i]);
    }
```

(`Clips[i] != null` part of condition added to check for error cropping up in comments below)

This checks if the clip has a parent specified (if it does, it's inside another clip) and removes it from that clip specifically, not just 'this'.

..and I'd also suggest using a Vector, rather than an Array - you can put any kind of value into an array, so if you put a non-DisplayObject in there you'll get an error when you try to remove if from the stage:

```
var clips:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
```

rather than:

```
var clips:Array = [];
```

Apart from the bulky declaration above, this functions exactly like an array in most respects (functions like push, splice, reference elements with square-bracket notation eg `clips[0]` etc), but will only let you put certain types of object/variable in it - in this case, DisplayObject. If you try to put an 'int' in there, it won't let you - it also runs a lot faster! They're worth using in any case, but here they may help just in case you've put something else in that array without realising (I've done it plenty of times).

Hope this helps!

Comment: i usually dont use Capitals, just for the example. I will try your method and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Ah ok, let me know how you get on with it. I've amended the last suggestion a bit as it didn't need the first part of the condition, hope you notice in time (only a quick change if you don't!)

Comment: your on the right page this is my error, which ever way i go about this "Parameter child must be non-null.", or cant be child of a parent.. i understand what they mean, im assuming there getting stored elsewhere

Comment: Ok, put trace('clip is: ' + Clips[i]) in before the removeChild is called, let me know what it outputs on the broken one. If you look up, I have amended the condition to take into account nulls (but this isn't a solution as to why they are!)

Comment: this works twice then throws errors:Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. 1++ think i have to re think

Comment: What does it say clip is? If it says 'clip is: null' then the problem's not with this bit of code, but where you're creating the clips in the first place - looks like you're putting a null value into the array. Use traces at this part of the program and see if/where it's happening. If you need any more help give me a shout.

Comment: if(Clips[i] != null && Clips[i].parent != null){
        Clips[i].parent.removeChild(Clips[i]);
    } // this was pritty much it

Comment: I really appreciate the guidance guys, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If it works then it means you are trying to remove the child from the wrong parent. That being the case you should be receiving runtime errors. If the following code does not cause errors but there is still content on the screen then you have code somewhere duplicating content. This can happen if the code that does the loading gets called twice.

```
      var len:int = Clips.length;
      for( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
      Clips[i].parent.removeChild(Clips[i]);        
      }
```

Comment: I thought i may have duplicated it twice, but when i trace the array its only shows 8 objects and 1 symbol

Comment: What happens with the above piece of code? If the loading code gets called twice then your array would show 8 objects as it overwrites the old array. The problem then is that the old array content is not garbage collected as it still has a reference (as the swfs are added to the stage). Try putting a trace statement in the block of code that does the loading.

Comment: What is the SLOTS array? You need to be removing from it.

Comment: if(Clips[i] != null && Clips[i].parent != null){
        Clips[i].parent.removeChild(Clips[i]);
    } checking the parents was the issue, seems they are scattered threw out my project in different parents, for my animation reasons

Comment: @parele While that does solve the problem, I chose not to suggest it as it fixes the symptoms and not the cause. This could lead to more problems later. You should try tracking down why there are nulls being pushed into your arrays.

Comment: Allan's right, when you get the time you ought to look at the code which is populating the arrays, as something's wrong with it and it could create more problems down the line.

Comment: i found the reason, : so this i dont think is a bad approach under the circumstances.i got 25 Dynamic movieClips that are inserted into 5 Dynamic movieClips spaced as columns. all inside another Dynamic MC:container with Dynmic mask, the reason is so i can create rendered pictures of 1 column containing 3 boxes(loaded in here are the swf copies )at runtime and animate it smoother. so the clips are scattered over 5 locations in different clips